# vim auto line finisher

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm searching for a specific line finisher. I'm pretty sure there already is a Plugin/Script/Command, but I can't find it -_-.

Ok, sometimes I'm in a line of code, and just want to go to the next line without going to the end of the line first, typing ';' and hit enter.

What I'm searching for is like, if I hit 'shift + enter' then:

- check if the line is closed with ';'
- if not --> go to the end and insert ';'
- if the line is already closed with ';' just go to the next line

Start:

[image: Start]

'shift + enter':

[image]

Thanks in advance ;_)

Answer (score 1):

A very complex mapping:

```
:nmap <silent> <expr> <Leader>c strpart(getline('.'), col('$')-2, 1) == ";" ? "j" : "A;<Esc><Home>j"
```

The above map uses a ternary operator that checks the last char of the line, if it is equal to ";"

```
strpart(getline('.'), col('$')-2, 1) == ";"
```

If the above expression is true, it runs a normal <kbd>j</kbd> otherwise it enters in insert mode at the end of the line with <kbd>A</kbd> and inserts a semicolon, exists insert mode and goes to the next line.

```
"A;<Esc><Home>j"
```

NOTE: make sure your leader key is set as you want, normaly it is backslash. in my case I have:

```
:let mapleader=','
```

Comment: Hey, I modified it a bit: I changed nmap to imap to be working in insert mode, but it still doesnt work. If I uses it  it just posts:    col('$')-2, 1) == ";" ? "j" : "A;<Esc><Home>j"

Comment: I think [@MrGreenPepper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13203137/mrgreenpepper), that in insert mode you have to protect Esc and home: `\<Esc>` `\<Home>`.